# How can i get a desired output from the below scenario

Tags: t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE1 (ID1 INT, ID2 VARCHAR(25))  
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (1,'A')  
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (2,'A,B')  
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (3,'A,B,C')  
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (4,'A,D')  
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (5,'A,B,C,D,E')

CREATE TABLE2 (ID1 VARCHAR(25), ID2 VARCHAR(25))  
INSERT INTO TABLE2 ('A','AAA')  
INSERT INTO TABLE2 ('B','BBB')  
INSERT INTO TABLE2 ('C','CCC')  
INSERT INTO TABLE2 ('D','DDD')  
INSERT INTO TABLE2 ('E','EEE')
```

I was asked this question in interview and the desired output needed was

```
COLUMN1 | COLUMN2   
1   |       AAA   
2   |       AAA,BBB  
3   |       AAA,BBB,CCC   
4   |       AAA,DDD  
5   |       AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE
```

Can someone guide me on this

Comment: I hope you just pasted the create and insert statements and didn't wrote them from scratch. You would fail the interview since both the table creation and insert statements are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for you using two cursors:

```
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @char VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @replacement VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @counter INT
DECLARE @result TABLE(COLUMN1 INT, COLUMN2 VARCHAR(25))
DECLARE @resultId INT = 1

DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT ID1, ID2
FROM TABLE1
OPEN @MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
INTO @id, @string
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @counter = 0
    DECLARE @MySecondCursor CURSOR
    SET @MySecondCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
    FOR
    SELECT ID1, ID2
    FROM TABLE2
    OPEN @MySecondCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MySecondCursor
    INTO @char, @replacement
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @counter = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @result(COLUMN1, COLUMN2) SELECT @resultId, REPLACE(@string, @char, @replacement)
            SET @counter = @counter + 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE @result SET COLUMN2 = (SELECT REPLACE(COLUMN2, @char, @replacement))
            WHERE COLUMN1 = @resultId
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM @MySecondCursor
        INTO @char, @replacement
    END
    CLOSE @MySecondCursor
    DEALLOCATE @MySecondCursor

    SET @resultId = @resultId + 1

    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
    INTO @id, @string
END

SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM @result
```

There may be a way better solution using `CTE`s but I'm not very familiar with them.

Comment: @Babulal, Hi, once you have sufficient reputation, you will be able to vote up questions and answers that you found helpful. That is the way of "Thank you" in SO.

Comment: @AbdulRasheed :-)

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this, using XML and CASE statments. More efficient than cursors,

```
SELECT Id1,
CASE WHEN id2 = 'A' THEN (SELECT ID2 FROM TABLE2 where ID1 = 'A') 
    WHEN id2 = 'A,B' THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING ( 
                            (
                                SELECT ','+ ID2 as [text()]
                                FROM TABLE2 where ID1 in ('A', 'B')
                                For XML PATH ('')
                            ), 2, 1000)) 
    WHEN id2 = 'A,B,C' THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING ( 
                            (
                                SELECT ','+ ID2 as [text()]
                                FROM TABLE2 where ID1 in ('A', 'B', 'C')
                                For XML PATH ('')
                            ), 2, 1000))
    WHEN id2 = 'A,D' THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING ( 
                            (
                                SELECT ','+ ID2 as [text()]
                                FROM TABLE2 where ID1 in ('A', 'D')
                                For XML PATH ('')
                            ), 2, 1000))
    WHEN id2 = 'A,B,C,D,E' THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING ( 
                            (
                                SELECT ','+ ID2 as [text()]
                                FROM TABLE2 where ID1 in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
                                For XML PATH ('')
                            ), 2, 1000)) END AS Result
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: @Babu - If my answer (query) meets your request, Could you please vote my answer? Thanks

Comment: Hey Naveen, I am new and need more reputation. When i collect some reputation i will do the first thing to vote the answer. Thanks again for reminding me to do so.